# Convert image to numpy dataset for tesseract ocr training

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset, tesseract

I am trying to create a dataset for tesseract. But unable to do so. The following code should output a csv file containing the image path and image label feature and .npz file. But the code does append any files in the csv

```
import numpy as np
import os
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array, load_img
import pandas as pd


image_dataset_dir = "datasets/images"
new_dataset_folder = "datasets/new"


dataset = {
    "image" :[],
    "label" : []
}
for label in os.listdir(image_dataset_dir):
     images_dir= image_dataset_dir + "/" + label
     if not os.path.isdir(images_dir):
        continue
     for image_file in os.listdir(images_dir):
#         if not image_file.endswith(".jpg", ".png",".tiff"):
#             continue 
        img = load_img(os.path.join(image_dataset_dir, label, image_file))
        x = img_to_array(img)                  
        

        rel_path = label + "/" + os.path.splitext(image_file)[0] + '.npz'
        os.makedirs(new_dataset_folder + "/" + label, exist_ok=True)
        npz_file = os.path.join(new_dataset_folder, rel_path)
        np.savez(npz_file, x)
#         print(rel_path)
        dataset["image"].append(rel_path)
        dataset["label"].append(label)

                         
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
df.to_csv(os.path.join(new_dataset_folder, "train.csv"), index=False)

print('Dataset converted to npz and saved here at %s '%new_dataset_folder)

df.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your objective, create files and save the output and their values.

.npz is none public zones, try using it with different backgrounds matching patterns.

Sample: Using Pandas ( data frame as your requirements ) and Tensorflow

```
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
BATCH_SIZE = 1
IMG_SIZE = (32, 32)
new_dataset_folder = "F:\\temp\\Python\\excel"

PATH = 'F:\\datasets\\downloads\\cats_name'
train_dir = os.path.join(PATH, 'train')
validation_dir = os.path.join(PATH, 'validation')

train_dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(train_dir, shuffle=True,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, image_size=IMG_SIZE)
                                                            
class_names = train_dataset.class_names

print( 'class_names: ' + str( class_names ) )
print( train_dataset )

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Dataset
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
dataset = {
    "image" :[],
    "label" : []
}

file_order = 0
for data in train_dataset :
    file_path = new_dataset_folder + "\\" + str(int(data[1][0])) + ".npz"
    dataset["image"].append(file_path)
    dataset["label"].append(str(int(data[1][0])))
    # Save
    encoding = "utf-8"
    with open( new_dataset_folder + "\\" + str(file_order), "wb" ) as f:
        f.write(str(data[0]).encode(encoding))
    
    file_order = file_order + 1

df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
df.to_csv(os.path.join(new_dataset_folder, "train.csv"), index=False)
```